# omniture fake page load tracking for scrolling / achored content

Tags: web-analytics, adobe-analytics

Looking through my business requirements, the web analytics team wants to make s.T() 'page load' calls when a user navigates to different sections on the same long ass page.  This is also supposed to happen when they scroll to or through this content.  I feel like this should perhaps be completed with a link tracking call, is that correct?  Is there a recommended approach for handling this scenario?  Are there any well document drawbacks to faking pageload omniture calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's absolutely no issues calling s.t() multiple times, as long as you want each of those calls treated as a page view.

Really the only differences between s.t() and s.tl() are as such:

- s.t() calls increment page views while s.tl() calls do not
- s.t() calls collect pageName and pageURL while s.tl() calls do not
- s.t() calls send all defined variables while s.tl() calls only send variables defined in s.linkTrackVars

Based on your business requirements, if you want additional page views to be incremented as they scroll through it, by all means use s.t(). If you want page views to only increment on actual page loads, consider using s.tl() calls.

Comment: good info.  How does omniture deal with duplicated requests?  Is it possible to get de-duped when using s.t()?

Comment: SiteCatalyst does not deduplicate requests in any way - it processes all data sent to their servers. You can achieve a form of deduplication using a VISTA rule from Adobe's engineering services team, however those are rather expensive and are generally only used when users paint themselves into a corner in their implementation. If you have the ability to revise your implementation, I'd recommend doing the deduplication on your end.